# Iterate between column names with user-defined table

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently working with c# and sql server managment studio:

I have a table like:

```
+--------+-------------+-------------+------+
| TaskId | Item2(bool) | Item3(bool) | etc… |
+--------+-------------+-------------+------+
```

I don't know bool column names because there are created dinamically from code (user create them).

Well I insert data when form open, with TaskId and all `bools` with `DEFAULT(0)`, si I have something like:

```
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+------+
|                TaskId                | Item2(bool) | Item3(bool) | etc… |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+------+
| 9B093907-2072-4F59-A55C-0003CE89EF9E |           0 |           0 |    0 |
+--------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+------+
```

I want to update booleans, so in c# I create datatable to use `User-defined tables`:

```
 DataTable checkboxList = new DataTable();
            var checkboxNameColumn = checkboxList.Columns.Add("CheckBoxName", typeof(string));
            var checkBoxValueColumns = checkboxList.Columns.Add("CheckBoxValue", typeof(bool));

            foreach (var c in checkBoxes)
            {
                var row = checkboxList.NewRow();
                row[checkboxNameColumn] = c.Name;
                row[checkBoxValueColumns] = c.Checked;
                checkboxList.Rows.Add(row);
            }


            Guid currentUser = new Guid(EBResources.EmpGuid);
            Guid currentTaskId = new Guid(TaskId);
            db.ExeSQLRedMarkItems($"usp_RedMarkItem_Insert", checkboxList, "@CheckBoxList", currentTaskId, currentUser);
```

CheckBoxName equals to my column Name and `CheckBoxValue` is value of that column. So I have my `Datatable` correct, now I send it to sql as:

User-defined table

```
CREATE TYPE [HELPER].CheckBoxValues AS TABLE(
CheckBoxName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CheckBoxValue BIT NOT NULL )
```

Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_RedMarkItem_Insert]
             -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
             @TaskId       UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
            , @CheckBoxList [Helper].[CheckBoxValues] READONLY
            , @CurrentUser  UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
AS
        BEGIN
            -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
            -- interfering with SELECT statements.
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @CurrentCheckboxName VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT
                                                        [CheckBoxName]
                                                        FROM @CheckBoxList)

               UPDATE [m]
                SET
                    @CurrentCheckboxName = [c].[CheckBoxValue]
                    FROM [RedMarkItems] [m]
                        JOIN @CheckBoxList [c] ON [c].[CheckBoxName] = @CurrentCheckboxName
                        WHERE m.TaskId = @TaskId
            END
```

So as you can see I declare `@CurrentCheckboxName`, but it throws me an error because that select return more than one value:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression.

What I need to do to iterate between column names? Regards

Comment: Do you have the option to change this design? SQL does not easily support dynamic column names. How about a related table with a column for the item number?

Comment: @DStanley is right: a table with a user-defined number of columns, with user-defined names, is going to be very hard to program against.  It is hard work, requiring a lot of debugging, to do ANYTHING in SQL where the table or column names are defined at run-time.

Comment: What I'd suggest: if you have an arbitrary number of fields, with arbitrary names, and you can't set them up with one row per user-defined field, consider using a chunk of XML to hold the field names and their values, rather than defining each user-defined field as a separate real-life SQL field.

Comment: Not all columns called Item1, Item2 etc.... that's just an example, it can be called Banana, Apple, whatever... that's why a related table not works @DStanley

Comment: @Jonathan But if they were all booleans, you could have both field name and field value as columns in a table, along with `TaskID`.

Comment: @Jonathan how about a table with columns `TaskId`, `ItemName`, `ItemValue`. then the rable could have entries where `ItemName` is `Banana`, `Apple`, etc. It is easier to query than one where the column names are not known.

Comment: It sounds really good, can you give me an example of update statement of it? @DStanley

Comment: `UPDATE items set value = Z where TaskId = X and ItemName = Y`

Comment: But there I don't know `set value`, I don't know column name... thats the real problem.. @DStanley

Answer (score 0):

you don't need the line below

```
  DECLARE @CurrentCheckboxName VARCHAR(255) = (SELECT
                                                    [CheckBoxName]
                                                    FROM @CheckBoxList)
```

you already have this inside @CheckBoxList. You need something like below

```
 UPDATE [m]
 SET m.val = [c].Val
 JOIN @CheckBoxList [c] 
     ON [c].[CheckBoxName] = m.CheckBoxName
 WHERE m.TaskId = @TaskId
```

---

you can get column names from Information_schema

```
SELECT
  TABLE_NAME,
  COLUMN_NAME
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: Problem is I don't know what column name is `m.val`. because name of column come in user-defined table that's why I declare it

Comment: Yes I can do as: `SELECT
  TABLE_NAME,
  COLUMN_NAME
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'RedMarkItems'`, but what I need to do once I get columns? I still need to know what is column name to use in UPDATE statement

Answer (score 0):

Your database design is going to give you a lot of problems. SQL Server works best with pre-defined tables with set numbers of named columns: while you can set up a system to have user-defined field labels, having actual user-defined *fields* is, in a sense, creating a database that runs on top of a database. You're going to need a lot of infrastructure, that you haven't created yet, to use and manage that.

My suggestion: if your need is for a single row with a collection of user-defined boolean values, store the boolean values as XML.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Task
(
   TaskId int,
   Checkboxes xml
)
```

Your XML would be defined something like this (though there are lots of ways you could define it!)

```
 <Checkboxes>
   <Checkbox name="User-defined name" value="True" />
   <Checkbox name="Some other name" value="False" />
 </Checkboxes>
```

You will still have some challenges -- for example, if you want to pull out all the rows that have a checkbox called "Apple" that had the value `true` -- but you'll have fewer than you would with an actual user-defined table.

And querying XML in a useful way is, in fact, possible.